# How to get Webview 'url' from AccessibilityNodeInfo

Tags: android, webview

Suppose ,I'm on the third party app say `Amazon`.

Now I'm able to access all of the window content using accessibility service and accessibility event type : `typeViewFocused`.

And I have a condition that if the window content contains class name `android.webkit.WebView` then I have to find the loaded URL for that Webview. But couldn't find the URL
, I can access all the content inside webview but I dont need the content of WebView I only need that URL which that webview used to load the content. Even I have checked all AccessibilityNodeInfo objects but not able to find URL